# How can I make Live chart on MIT-App-Inventor

Tags: json, firebase, app-inventor

I am connecting google firebase with MIT App inventor and could able to send and receive vales using json decode and encode options.
Is there a way to plot the data in to a live chart? Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Probably. What did you have in mind? Have you made an attempt so far that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

A variety of charting options for App Inventor can be found here:
[FAQ Section: Charts and Graphs](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/faq-section-charts-and-graphs/1684/2)